# Preventing false positives with Leak Canary

Tags: android, leakcanary

We observe a lot of false-positives with Leak Canary, ie., Leak Canary detects that there is a leak but later comes back with the message:

```
LeakCanary: * NO LEAK FOUND.
```

I think this is because GC didn't claim the object in time. Is there anything that we could do to reduce these false positives ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at LogCat with filter `LeakCanary`.
There's a message when suspicious reference not GC collected. Right before dump start.
In this message you'll see class name.