# Weird android webview memory leak

Tags: android, webview, memory-leaks, kotlin

I have already spent 2 days trying to figure out the issue. What happens is I simply inflate the layout that consists of the WebView inside constraint layout. Then I have this code that essentially loads a page and clears the WebView in onDestroy().

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main)
        find<Webn>(R.id.webview).loadUrl("url")
//        watch(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        find<Webn>(R.id.webview).reset()
    }
}
```

Somehow this causes a memory leak! How??? This is as simple as it gets. I installed leak canary and tried to profile this and traces led me to internal android classes that hold a reference to the activity. I tried to set them all to null via reflection but it once I release one reference another pops up. What is going on and how can I fix it?

Here is the latest trace from LeakCanary. The reference to MainActivity is in the mBase field but navigating all the way to this class and trying to set this field gives NoSuchFieldException. Which means I can not access it even via reflection.

[image]

Comment: "this is as simple as it gets" -- but you call into custom code which you haven't shown. Also i'm not sure what exactly definition of "memory leak" we're working against here. Could it be a false positive?

Comment: The only custom code here is reset() which incapsulates WebView.destroy() and reflection calls. When I remove it is still produces a memory leak. As for definition you can see in leakcananry screenshot that MainActivity is leaking.

Comment: `find()` is your custom function too, isn't it?

Comment: "you can see in leakcananry screenshot that MainActivity is leaking" -- i don't see the _definition_ of "leaking" there. What exactly condition does the tool detect? Under what conditions does it declare something as a "leak"?

Comment: This should be relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557329/preventing-false-positives-with-leak-canary And generally google for "leakcanary false positive", you'll get many hits.

Comment: find() is a Kotlin extension function that is short for findViewById. Also I know that LeakCanary fails some time but I did the same thing with AS profiler and found the same thing. What essential happens is a Webview routes the reference of MainActiivty to other classes and does not release those reference when they no longer needed. Ans this causes a me moth leak.

Comment: Basically a bug in WebView?

Comment: I am starting to think so but how come no one noticed it?

Comment: The web seems to be teeming with pages on the topic of "Android WebView leaks memory".

Answer (score 0):

First of all i am not able to find the `reset()` method on `Webview` and seconds thing is you don't need to `reset()` `Webview` on `onDestroy()`

Instead you should do this on `onPause()` and `onResume()` like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mWebView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mWebView.onResume();
    }
```

Comment: reset() is my custom method where I call destroy() and do reflection stuff

Comment: I deleted onDestroy() and added resume and pause. Still memory leak

Comment: Reflection is kind of heavy task and and we dont recommend to do any heavy task on `onDestroy()` rather its used to cleanup the resources